# java is try with resources the industry standard

Tags: java, try-catch

Are there any pitfalls to try with resources opposed to closing a resource in some other fashion? Or is the try with resources the number one way recommended for implementing a try?

Comment: Your headline question is meaningless without credible statistics, but it is certainly the best way.

Comment: the headline was more just being facetious. 
Thank you for the response though.

Comment: Of course there's other ways to do it, we've been doing it other ways for more then 15 years ( with Java), but, in my personal experience, try with resources is significantly simpler are more robust and one of the features of Java 7 I use all the time

Comment: two programmers from Melbourne in two minutes? that place must be breeding programmers like rabbits
Thank you both for the input

Comment: @Schrodinger's_hat you cant use it with objects which don't implement `AutoClosable` so if an API uses `disconnect` to close in the end, you still need to do it old way.

Comment: @Schrodinger's_hat I didn't say anything about facetiousness. I have bad news for you, there are more than two programmers in Melbourne.

Comment: @Shail016 thank you, this was the kind of clarification I was looking for. I don't quite understand why this question is seen as opinion based when there is a quantifiable answer as you have given

Comment: @Schrodinger's_hat May be your question sounds like that. May be your questions heading and content don't match :) ?

Answer (score 2):

```
InputStream stream = new MyInputStream(...);
try {
    // ... use stream
} catch(IOException e) {
   // handle exception
} finally {
    try {
        if(stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        // handle yet another possible exception
    }
}
```

Did you see that nested try-catch need to be implemented in the `finally` block.
To avoid this tedious work,we can use try with resources.

```
try (InputStream stream = new MyInputStream(...)){
    // ... use stream
} catch(IOException e) {
   // handle exception
}
```

To answer your question more specifically, **YES** , try with resources is the most efficient and easy way and is being widely used as per industry standards are considered.

**NOTE** : The code is just for depicting a situation to support my answer.